# loading from an XML file into PHP to generate content

Tags: php, xml

So what I am trying to do is load data from an XML file into php and use those variables to generate content. For each item i want to get a new set of variable values and print them out onto the page. If there are 4 interfaceItems then it should print 4 displayWrappers with 4 unique titles. This isn't working for me. Is there a better or more efficient way of doing this? The errors I am getting right now are:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
<?php

$xmldata = simplexml_load_file('elements.xml');
foreach($xmldata->portfolio->interface->interfaceItem as $item) :?>
<?php
$title = ($item->title);
$desc = ($item->description);
$whatOne = ($item->whatOne);    
$whatTwo = ($item->whatTwo);
$location = ($item->location);      

?>
<div class="displayWrapper">
    <div class="display">
        <p> <?=$title ?> </p>
    </div>
</div>



<?php endforeach;?>




<portfolio>
<interface>
    <interfaceItem>
        <title>modi tempora</title>
        <decription>lorum ipsum</decription>
        <whatOne> dolor sit amet</whatOne>
        <whatTwo>sed quia non</whatTwo>         
        <location>i/blah.jpg</location>
    </interfaceItem>
    <interfaceItem>
        <title>magnam aliquam</title>
        <decription>omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus.</decription>
        <whatOne>expedita distinctio</whatOne>
        <whatTwo>possimus, omnis voluptas</whatTwo>         
        <location>i/blah2.jpg</location>
    </interfaceItem>
</interface>
</portfolio>
```

Comment: Those error messages usually have more information such as line number and file (though in this case it's fairly obvious). Also, we'd need to see an example of your XML file

Comment: I am guessing because you move so far into the object tier there that interfaceItem is not an object but element, or it's not an array

Comment: Debug your code with `var_dump($xmldata);` right before your `foreach`.

Comment: Where does portfolio come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild stab in the dark here and reduce it down to one or both of two possible problems.

#### Scenario 1

Your XML file looks like this

```
<portfolio>
    <interface>
        <interfaceItem>
```

With SimleXML, the first element is the root node. You would need to change your code to use

```
foreach ($xmldata->interface->interfaceItem as $item)
```

#### Scenario 2

SimpleXML element iteration is case sensitive. If your XML looks like this

```
<root>
    <Portfolio>
        <Interface>
            <InterfaceItem>
```

You would need to change your code to

```
foreach ($xmldata->Portfolio->Interface->InterfaceItem as $item)
```

### Update

Given the XML sample in your question, if that is the contents of `elements.xml`, it would simply be

```
foreach ($xmldata->interfaceItem as $item)
```

Comment: perfect! scenario one was the answer. Thank you very much.